# android battery usage graph is like 1/x

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6, 7.1-nougat

[image]

Can some1 explain this? can i fix this problem with calibrating battery? basically it lasts almost as long as ever, but the percentages make it impossible for me to know how long do i have till it dies. it is now 10hrs on 1% battery...(samsung s6 nougat OS)

Comment: Calibrate the battery there is plenty of app for that on play store.

Answer (score 0):

> **How to calibrate an Android device battery without root access**
>
> The old 'fully charge and discharge' approach stands as one of the simplest ways to 'recalibrate' your Android battery. But if your phone battery is causing you real problems, it's worth taking the risk.
>
> Method 1
>
> 2. Turn it on again and let it turn itself off.
> 3. Plug your phone into a charger and, without turning it on, let it charge until the on-screen or LED indicator says 100 percent.
> 4. Unplug your charger.
> 5. Turn your phone on. It's likely that the battery indicator won't say 100 percent, so plug the charger back in (leave your phone on) and continue charging until it says 100 percent on-screen as well.
> 6. Unplug your phone and restart it. If it doesn't say 100 percent plug the charger back in until it says 100 percent on screen.
> 7. Repeat this cycle until it says 100 percent (or as close as you think it's going to get) when you start it up without being plugged in.
> 8. Now, let your battery discharge all the way down to 0 percent and let your phone turn off again.
> 9. Fully charge the battery one more time without interruption and you should have reset the Android system's battery percentage.
>
> Remember that it is not recommended to perform this process all the time. Even when your battery is so dead your phone won't even turn on, your battery still has enough reserve charge to avoid system damage. But you don't want to poke the tiger with a stick. Perform this process once every three months at the most. If it is required more often than that you have bigger problems at hand.
>
> Put plainly: fully discharging a battery is bad for it. Trying to overload a battery is also bad for it. The good news is that charging batteries automatically shut off when their safe limit is reached and there's always a little in reserve even if your phone won't start. But again: do this only when really necessary, because it does have a negative impact on battery life.
>
> **How to calibrate Android device battery with root access**
>
> Even though I'm not convinced that clearing the batterystats.bin file has any meaningful effect on how the Android system reports remaining battery charge, there are those who swear by this method.
>
> So in the interests of fairness, we've included the process for you here (it is true that different manufacturers use the batterystats.bin file for different things). It's basically the same process as above but with the added step of a root-enabled app.
>
> Method 2
>
> 1. Discharge your phone fully until it turns itself off.
> 2. Turn it on and let it turn off again.
> 3. Plug your phone into a charger and, without turning it on, let it charge until the on-screen or LED indicator says 100 percent.
> 4. Unplug your charger.
> 5. Turn your phone on. It's likely that the battery indicator won't say 100 percent, so plug the charger back in (leave your phone on) and continue charging until it says 100 percent on the screen as well.
> 6. Unplug your phone and restart it. If it doesn't say 100 percent, plug the charger back in until it says 100 percent on screen.
> 7. You want to repeat this cycle until it says 100 percent (or as close as you think it's going to get) when you start it up without being plugged in.
> 8. Now, install the [Battery Calibration app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT) and, before you launch it, make sure your battery is at 100 percent again, then restart.
> 9. Immediately launch the app and recalibrate your battery.
> 10. Once you've calibrated your battery, discharge it all the way down to 0 percent and let your phone turn off again.
> 11. Fully charge the battery one more time without interruption while it's switched off, and the Android system's battery percentage will be reset.
>
> That's it. Have you tried any of these methods? Do you know an alternate way to fix battery problems? Let me know in the comments.

[Source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-how-to-callibrate-battery-device-t3308554)